# How to sort HTML elements by <TD> date and delete duplicates by <A> in Java?

Tags: java, html, html-table, jsoup, attr

I have an HTML snippet that I need to change around in Java, I have been using JSOUP to parse through, but I feel like it may not be as efficient. I uploaded pictures of what I am looking for here.  Sorting from date of the TD news to oldest & if there is duplicat A hrefs delete the node as a whole.
I have an arraylist of the given divs that will be included as well

```
ObservableList<String> names;
```

Im thinking the a way could be to foreach through the list and grab from that name all the way down until a div is hit? I feel like this is a simple problem and im over thinking it, thank you for the help!

```
foreach(String name: names)
{}
```

[Before example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvTKO.png)

[Sorted without duplicates example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnUKX.png)

HTML(no sort with duplicates):

```
<div>CHTR</div>
<td width="130" align="right" style="white-space:nowrap">Mar-04-20 08:54AM&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
</br>
<a sname='CHTR' href="https://test.com/news/why-charter-chtr-stock-might-135401270.html" target="_blank" class="tab-link-news">Why Charter (CHTR) Stock Might be a Great Pick</a></br>
<td width="130" align="right">Mar-04-20 08:53AM&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
</br>
<a sname='CHTR' href="https://test.com/news/charter-offers-senior-unsecured-notes-135400843.html" target="_blank" class="tab-link-news">Charter Offers Senior Unsecured Notes</a>. 
</br>
<div>PEGI</div>
<td width="130" align="right" style="white-space:nowrap">Mar-04-20 12:49 PM&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
</br>
<a sname='PEGI' href="www.test.com/news/3548648-pattern-energy-low-odds-of-competing-bid-raymond-james-says">Pattern Energy has low odds of competing bid, Raymond James says</a></br>
<div>CHTR</div>
<td width="130" align="right" style="white-space:nowrap">Mar-04-20 12:39 PM&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
</br>
<a sname='CHTR' href="www.test.com/news/3548649-charter-offering-senior-notes">Charter offering more senior notes</a></br>
<div>PEGI</div>
<td width="130" align="right" style="white-space:nowrap">Mar-04-20 12:49 PM&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
</br>
<a sname='PEGI' href="www.test.com/news/3548648-pattern-energy-low-odds-of-competing-bid-raymond-james-says">Pattern Energy has low odds of competing bid, Raymond James says</a></br>
<td width="130" align="right" style="white-space:nowrap">Mar-04-20 08:40 AM&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
</br>
<a sname='PEGI' href="www.test.com/news/greatbuy">Great buy with PEGI</a></br>
```

Comment: This HTML is invalid (`td` children inside a `div`?). Jsoup doesn't parse it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsed the HTML and added them to a list, then created a custom Object, then two comparators to double sort the list.

```
    Comparator<MyObject> compareByName = Comparator
         .comparing(Article::getName);

    Comparator<MyObject> compareByName2 = Comparator
             .comparing(MyObject::getDate).reversed();

    myList.sort(compareByName.thenComparing(compareByName2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood it right, but what about parsing the Html into a `HashMap` to get key-value pairs? That would get rid of duplication at least. Then you could do something like:

```
List<Employee> employeeById = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
Collections.sort(employeeById);
```

And get the results as:

```
[Employee{id=1, name='Mher'}, 
Employee{id=2, name='George'}, 
Employee{id=8, name='John'}, 
Employee{id=22, name='Annie'}]
```

Source: https://www.baeldung.com/java-hashmap-sort